# Need help writing difficult condition regarding validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so what i need to do is i want to make signature field optional on certain condition if my chequebook === "NO" and account is 'Asaan Digital Account' || 'Asaan Digital Remittance Account' only then i want to make the signature field optional and if chequebook === "YES" and account is 'Asaan Digital Account' || 'Asaan Digital Remittance Account' only then i want to make signature field required and other than that all accounts by default required signature field and right now signature field is required

```
const files = [...attachmentType[i].attachments];
const addedFiles = [];
for (var m = 0; m < files.length; m++) {
  const signatureOptional =
    (state.applicantList[0].chequebook === "NO" &&
      account &&
      account.get("product") === "Asaan Digital Account") ||
    (account && account.get("product") === "Asaan Digital Remittance Account")
      ? files[m].value = "SIGNATURE_SCAN"
      : "";
    console.log(signatureOptional, 'hello world');
  if (files[m].files.length === 0 && files[m].value !== "OTHER" && !signatureOptional) {
           
    addedFiles.push({
      primaryText: files[m].primaryText,
      validationResult: files[m].validationRequired,
    });
          
  }
}
```

so here is the implementation i made it optional for all the accounts by doing this

```
const files = [...attachmentType[i].attachments];
const addedFiles = [];
for (var m = 0; m < files.length; m++) {
  if (files[m].files.length === 0 && files[m].value !== "OTHER" && files[m].value !== "SIGNATURE_SCAN") {     
    addedFiles.push({
      primaryText: files[m].primaryText,
      validationResult: files[m].validationRequired,
    });
  }
}
let missingDocument = [...props.invalidType]
missingDocument = missingDocument.filter((data) => data.primaryText !== 'Other documents (optional)' && data.primaryText !== 'Signature Scan')
```

it convert my signature field to optional on every account and missingDocument is the array in which invalidType is saved and basically invalidType is addedFiles so i am filtering out these two

so according to my requirement i have made these changes in the first code I have provided but nothing works can someone help me writting this complex condition

Comment: I think you need to clarify your requirement for us. You say "it convert my signature field to optional" - Is this part of the desired behavior or something it is doing incorrectly? I would be helpful to define the relevant properties of the `attachments[]` elements, as well as what you would expect the output to look like.

Comment: It is also not clear what to the two pieces of code are... Is the top one old code and the bottom one your new code. Is the new code "better" than the old code?

Comment: Move your condition into a separate function like `function isSignatureOptional(...) { ... }` and it'll be easier to write.

Comment: @AKX I was about to suggest the same, but I would personally suggest the function name `isSignatureRequired`. This makes easier to understand whenever you need to invert `!` the expression. `!isSignatureRequired` is easier to understand than `!isSignatureOptional`. Similar to how `!isValid` is easier to understand than `!isInvalid`.

Comment: @ElRonnoco what i have added in the first code was i am trying to build a condition myself so I have used if condition and write this code but it did not work and in the second code my signature field is by default mandatory so I was checking if i am able to convert the field to optional so i added && files[m].value !== "SIGNATURE_SCAN")
this condition in the prev code and added && data.primaryText !== 'Signature Scan'
this in the missing doc variable so it's now successfully converting the field to optional in all the cases

Comment: @AKX how can u pls write it because in the first code i wrote some condition but it will not work so can u guide me how can i write that function according to my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your top section of code breaking out the logic you describe into a function gives something like this...

```js
const files = [...attachmentType[i].attachments];

const addedFiles = [];

for (var m = 0; m < files.length; m++) {
  const signatureOptional = !isSignatureRequired(
    state.applicantList[0].chequebook,
    account && account.get("product")
  );
  if (files[m].files.length === 0 && files[m].value !== "OTHER" && !signatureOptional) {      
    addedFiles.push({
      primaryText: files[m].primaryText,
      validationResult: files[m].validationRequired,
    });        
  }
}

function isSignatureRequired(checkbook, account) {
    // signature is mandatory for all circumstances other than checkbook = NO and these two accounts.
    return !(
        checkbook === 'NO' && 
        (account == 'Asaan Digital Account' || account == 'Asaan Digital Remittance Account')
    );
}
```

However, what you are providing as input and what you are expecting as output is unclear. For example, what are you expecting to be in `addedFiles` at the end of this process?

Further - It would appear this code is very susceptible to malicious client-side attack - e.g. it would be very easy for an attacker to override this and set "signature not required". Obviously, I don't know if this presents you any danger. But, *always validate on the server!*